# Difference between Web Socket in Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: websocket, arduino, raspberry-pi

I use Web socket between Raspberry Pi and server and it works perfect, as the theory of web socket.

But when I search for a web socket for Arduino I found a lot of libraries and may be all of them is just like http post not like the real web socket.
They just send posts and receive gets, but the Web socket is to open connection between the 2 terminals and they send posts and wait for the a message from the other side.

In my Arduino application I always need to send http get requests to know the state of the led from server, which leads to too much traffics, but when using a Web Socket the server only sends a message for the Arduino when the state is changed, and the Arduino only waits for the message.

Does any one know a real web socket library for Arduino?

Comment: Websockets is a protocol that uses TCP/IP sockets (and starts as an HTTP connection)... the `socket` tag is for sockets - the TCP/IP, UDP, Berklee types - not Websockets. I'm removing the tag.

Comment: Did you happen to read [this](https://kevinrohling.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/world-domination-using-arduinos-and-websockets/) article? it appears that what you want to do is indeed possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Real" websocket library for Arduino.

I recommend using Raspberry Pi farther than Arduino because it is more stable than Arduino since it has an operating system and supports multi processes ( unlike the Arduino which runs only one process at a time).

If you compare the price of RPi and any Arduino with build in WiFi you will find that they have the same price approximately.